# Call div in another page as inside a dialog box

Tags: jquery, html

I have developed a website using a template. There, a dialog box is prompt properly when click on a  tag. But I need to call the dialog box div which is in another different page. Because I need to get a id which is passing from the URL to use with the GET['id'] with PHP.
I have tried calling the div in this way

```
 <a href="x.html#myModal2">Alert</a>
```

But its not working. Any one can give me a suggestion or a guidance to achieve my objective?

here is my calling tag and the dialog box div

```
    <a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal">Alert</a>
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel2">Alert Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Body goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn green">OK</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here is the same div which I need to call in the x.html page

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel1">Modal Header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Body goes here...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn yellow">Save</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*IMHO* you cannot.

Pass some query parameter and then do it in `document.ready()` of that page